# regular expression to joining repeatable field

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have to join 260  \$b and 260  \$c filed to 260  \$a filed

```
    =LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 45e0
    =008  010101s9999\\\\xx\\\\\\\\\\\\000\0\und\d
    =020  \\$a140257586
    =041  \\$aeng
    =080  \\$a321.78:2(540)BAS
    =100  \\$aBasu, Kaushik, eds.
    =245  \0$aUnravelling the nation
    =245  \0$bsectarian conflict and India's secular identity
    =245  \0$cedited by Kaushik Basu and Sanjay Subrahmanyam.
    =260  \\$aNew Delhi
    =260  \\$bPenguin
    =260  \\$c1996
    =300  \\$a244 p.
    =300  \\$c19.00 cm.
```

Comment: Please proofread your posts. Writing `\\\` does not do what you think it does. When you say "filed" do you mean "field"?

Answer (score 0):

Find:
    (=260.*\$a.*)\r\n *=260.*\$b(.*)\r\n *=260.*\$c(.*)

Replace with:
    \1 :$b\2,$c\3

To brake it down:
The first parenthesis `(=260.*\$a.*)` matches the first row, `\r\n` the linebreak `*=260.*\$b(.*)`, the second row `\r\n` another linebreak and `*=260.*\$c(.*)` the third row.

We then string together the matches from the  three parenthesis according to MARC on a new row.

Comment: You're assuming some things that the OP never states in this (badly asked) question. But your RE won't work anyway. `(=260\s*\\\\\$a.*)[\s\S]*?=260\s*\\\\\$b(.*)[\s\S]*?=260\s*\\\\\$c(.*)` might be a solution though, if your assumptions are correct. [See regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uA9mL1/1).

Comment: Well it worked when I tried it in notepad++ :-)

But knowing a little bit about MARC which is the fileformat in question I know that fields 260 subfield a, b and c always look like that, (It would even be safe to specify the leading spaces explicitly since its a old fixfield format.

The MARC file will be formally invalid afterwards since 260 a is "Place of publication, distribution, etc." and not "Place, Name and Date of publication, distribution, etc.", but that is left to the librarian to care for...

Comment: Reading up on MARC I realise that my replace pattern is wrong, will update.